# How to implement Custom Async Validator in Angular2/4/5

Tags: typescript, angular

**1.** Is it even supported by Angular yet ? see [this](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/1068) open issue

**2.** If it is, then what is wrong in the code below

```
export class someClass{

    myForm:ControlGroup;

    constructor(public http:Http, public formBuilder:FormBuilder)
       this.myForm = formBuilder.group({
            ImageId: ["", Validators.required, this.asynValidator]
    });

    asyncValidator(control: Control): {[key: string]: any} {

        return new Promise (resolve => {

          let headers = new Headers();
          headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/json');

          this.http.get('http://localhost/ImageIdValidate?id='+ control.value, {headers:headers})
                .map(res => res.json())
                .subscribe(data => {
                    console.log(data);
                    if(data != null) {
                        resolve({"duplicate": true})
                    }
                    else resolve(null);      
                })
            });
        });
      }
    }
```

It doesn't even make a server request.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

You need to bind your method on the component instance itself as described below:

```
this.myForm = formBuilder.group({
            ImageId: ["",    
               Validators.required, 
               this.asynValidator.bind(this)]
    });
```

Otherwise you won't be able to use the http property to execute your request.

This article could also give you some hints about asynchronous form validation (see the section "asynchronous validation"):

- http://restlet.com/blog/2016/02/17/implementing-angular2-forms-beyond-basics-part-2/

Comment: In fact, it's the way JavaScript works. When you reference a method you lose the object it's attached on. You can force this using the bind method...

Comment: When I start to think that I'm on my way to be a PRO someday, things like this make me laugh.

But anyway, is [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20279484/how-to-access-the-correct-this-context-inside-a-callback) related ?

Comment: In fact OOP in JavaScript is different front the ones of languages like Java and C++. With the class keyword, you don't really define "true" classes like with languages. JavaScript usés prototype-based OOP. Yes the question you quoted is related to this problem.

Comment: And @ThierryTemplier's other answer [showing an alternative to `.bind()` using a closure](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38900747/http-doesnt-work-in-angular-2-custom-asynchronous-validation).

Answer (score 3):

as of newer versions of Angular, but pre version `5.0.0` you would add the async validator as the third argument for your formcontrol:

```
myControl: ['', [Validators.required], [this.asyncValidator.bind(this)]]
```

since version `5.0.0` you can now mark the validators like so:

```
myControl: ['', {validators: [Validators.required], 
                 asyncValidators:[this.asyncValidator.bind(this)]}]
```

Comment: I just implemented an async validation function, and I also had to add `NG_ASYNC_VALIDATORS` provider to the component! (Which is an annoying bit of magic!!)

Answer (score 0):

Hello guys thanks for the solution.
However it didnt work for me outta the box.

the problem was the async validator had to be a next parameter as part of the validators. so what worked for me was

```
this.myForm = formBuilder.group({
        ImageId: ["",    
           [Validators.required], 
           [this.asynValidator.bind(this)]]
});
```

and tadaa!! the headache was gone.
hope it helps someone.

Comment: The only difference i can see is you added some extra [] comparing to the answer post. And you have not mentioned why is the extra [] require. This is not a helpful anser

Comment: The extra [] brackets are required because async validators now have to be listed as the third parameter.  Sync validators are listed in the second parameter, async validators in the third.